# How to filter and sum values in pyspark dataframe with conditions in column

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have pyspark dataframe:

```
+---+------------------+
|Id |Friend_Ids|Points |
+------+-------+-------+
|1  |[2, 5]    | 5     |
|2  |[1, 3, 4] | 6     |
|3  |[2, 4]    | 2     |
|4  |[3, 5, 2] | 12    |
|5  |[1, 4]    | 1     |
+------+-------+-------+
```

I want to get a column with sum of points of friends of each id:

```
+---+------------------+-------------------+
|Id |Friend_Ids|Points |Friends_points_sum |
+------+-------+-------+-------------------+
|1  |[2, 5]    | 5     | 7                 |
|2  |[1, 3, 4] | 6     | 19                |
|3  |[2, 4]    | 2     | 18                |
|4  |[2, 3, 5] | 12    | 9                 |
|5  |[1, 4]    | 1     | 17                |
+------+-------+-------+-------------------+
```

I have tried this

```
df.withColumn("friends_points_sum",df.filter(F.col('Id').isin(F.col('Friends_Ids'))\
                                                           .agg(F.sum('points')).collect()[0][0])
```

and get `TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable`

I have also tried udf like

```
def sum_agg(array, df):
    id = array[0]
    friend_ids = array[1]
    points = array[2]
    s = df.filter(F.col(id).isin(friend_id)).agg(F.sum('points')).collect()[0][0]
    return s.tolist()
points_sum = F.udf(qnty_agg, IntegerType())

df.withColumn("friends_points_sum", qnty_sum(F.array('id','Friend_Ids','Points'), df))
```

but it does not accept df as an argument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to `explode` the *friend_ids* column first, then self join the dataframe to lookup the value of *points*, then finally aggregate the values

```
df = (df
      .selectExpr('id', 'points', 'explode(friend_ids) fi')
      .join(df.selectExpr('id i', 'points pts'), F.col('fi') == F.col('i'), 'inner')
      .groupby('id', 'points')
      .agg(F.collect_list('fi').alias('friend_ids'), F.sum('pts').alias('friend_points_sum')))
df.show()

+---+------+----------+-----------------+
| id|points|friend_ids|friend_points_sum|
+---+------+----------+-----------------+
|  3|     2|    [2, 4]|               18|
|  1|     5|    [5, 2]|                7|
|  5|     1|    [1, 4]|               17|
|  4|    12| [5, 2, 3]|                9|
|  2|     6| [1, 3, 4]|               19|
+---+------+----------+-----------------+
```